# Backbone routing not firing first time

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have started learning Backbone.js. I have set up a simple router for 3 links. 2 of them fire routing perfectly but one - the one with `href="#/active"` in the code below, will not fire the routing until I have clicked one of the other 2 links first.

Html is:
    `<ul id = filters>
        <li>
        <a class="selected" href="#/">All</a>
    </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/active">Active</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/completed">Completed</a>
            </li>
        </ul>`

Javascript:

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '*filter': 'setFilter'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.on('route:setFilter', this.setFilt);
    },

    setFilt: function(param) {
        app.TodoFilter = param || '';
        app.Todos.trigger('filter');
    }
});
app.TodoRouter = new Workspace();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: where is the route for `active` defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Routers don't work like that, try this way.

> routes: {
>
> ```
>     'filter': 'setFilter',
>
>     'active': 'activeRoter',
>
>     'completed':'completedRouter'
> },
>
>  setFilter: function(){
>     //Do something
>   },
>
>  activeRoter: function(){
>    //Do something
>   },
>  completedRouter: function(){
>    //Do something
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, The routing I am using uses a splat to declares a default route that contains one parameter - the parameter name is `filter` and this gets passed as the `param` parameter in the `setFilt(param)`. I've discovered that the problem is not with my routing as such. When I load the app first, all routes work fine. The problem is when I refresh the page wile I am on one route e.g with url `http://localhost:5000/todo.html#/active`. The `setFilt` functions is getting called before the page is fully rendered. Then when I click the Active link again, Backbone sees I am already on the correct route so `setFilt` function is not triggered. I need to look more into how to fix this but it is a tutorial that I am doing so I will move on for the moment. Thanks for your help though..